# Match columns of two dataframe and if matched then get the respective columns from 1st dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe :

df1:

[image]

and df2:

[image]

I want to match `col1` of `df1` with `col_new` of `df2`. If they match then I want to extract the first `label` from `df1`.
My desired output is :

[image]

I am using the below code :

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col_new'))
```

but it is creating more number of records as there are multiple labels assign to single value.

Comment: use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicates.

Comment: getting this error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
out = (df1.drop_duplicates('col1').merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col_new'))
```

It suppose to keep only the first value from df1 if there are duplicates.